# Orbits around an infinite line of point masses

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

Let's say that there is a line of point masses of mass $M$, separated by distace $d$, extending to infinity. Like this:
[image]

A test mass of mass $m$ moves in the gravitational potential created by the large masses. What types of orbits are possible?

Bound orbits around one of the masses should be a possibility and should also be stable to perturbations. (Denoted by 1 on the figure.)

In the plane that bisects the line between two masses (X), the forces are only directed in that plane. This leads me to believe that orbits such as 2 are possible, but should be unstable (at least to perturbations that move them out of the plane).

But this clearly doesn't exhaust all orbit types. What other types of orbits are possible - e.g., can something like a helix orbit (denoted by ?) happen?

Comment: are you talking of gravity? point masses for other forces need quantum mechanics, no orbits but orbitals.

Comment: Gravity. I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Your system is not stable, the points will gravitate to  each other and cannot be kept at the positions you draw, to allow for test masses about one of them at the smallest perturbation which will happen when you try to order them that way.